# Undefined function link_to in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, php-5.2

I was trying to create a view in Laravel 5, I used the function link_to to create some html link but to my dismay; I got an error as below:

**FatalErrorException 
Call to undefined function link_to()**

Was this function removed?
I know the alternative is to write the actual HTML as `<a href='url'>Label</a>` but I would prefer to use some function like link_to('url','label');

Comment: What does the documentation say?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`link_to` is actually `illuminate/html` helpers which you need to add manually using `composer require "illuminate/html=~5.0"` or convert to use `url()` instead.

Comment: Thank you crynobone... I actually used  laravelcollective/html and all is now ok..but I'm still wondering why the html helpers were dropped in laravel 5. was it an attempt to make it lighter?

Comment: Because everyone had different idea on what the packages should provide, which made Taylor realise that it better to just let the community handle it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a method presented in Illuminate\Html\HtmlBuilder.php

```
/**
 * Generate a HTML link.
 *
 * @param  string  $url
 * @param  string  $title
 * @param  array   $attributes
 * @param  bool    $secure
 * @return string
 */
public function link($url, $title = null, $attributes = array(), $secure = null) { ... }
```

Instead of using link_to or link_to_*, you can find alternative methods registered in facades. If you set the alias as

```
'Html'      => 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade'
```

you can try something like

```
{!! Html::link('url', 'label') !!}
```

which will give exactly the same function. Hope this post will be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

There's no link_to function. Use url instead:

```
{!! url('path', $task->title) !!}
```

Comment: hey you can just add the HTML helpers

Comment: this is not correct - link_to() and url() do different things ... the former outputs an HTML tag, the latter just outputs a URL

Comment: This is not an option, url() does not generare the complete anchor script